# Integral with Dirac and Heaviside function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I want to prove that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta (x) f(\theta (x)) dx = \int_0 ^1 f(y)dy $$

for smooth functions f(y)

where $$\delta (x)$$ is Dirac delta and $$ \theta(x) $$ is the Heaviside function.

I know that the derivative of the Heaviside function is the Dirac function, which seems the only identity that I can use, along with other properties of the Dirac function, but I cannot work the integral.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: Note that $f(H(x))=f(0)+(f(1)−f(0))H(x)$. Inasmuch as the distribution $\langle \delta,H\rangle $ does not exist, the distribution $\langle\delta,foH\rangle $ does not exist either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure whether it makes sense or not, because $f(\theta(x)) = f(1), \ x > 0, \ = \ f(0), \ x < 0,$ in general will not have finite support and is not smooth at $x = 0$.

The idea of the exercise is probably to use integration by substitution. Since $\delta(x) = \theta(x)'$, you can do a change of variables $y = \theta(x)$, $dy = \theta(x)'dx = \delta(x)dx.$ Then $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)f(\theta(x))dx = \int_{\theta(-\infty)}^{\theta(\infty)} f(y)dy = \int_0^1 f(y)dy.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
That's what I tried to do, but then I realized that while the Heaviside function is smooth, we can't be certain about the f( /theta(x)).

Comment: @DVader Ok, no problem. Where did you find the question?

Comment: A friend sent it to me to check it out a couple of days back.

Comment: @DVader Ah, ok.

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout Your first statement is correct. Here as you pointed out, $f(H(x))=f(0)+(f(1)−f(0))H(x)$. Inasmuch as the distribution $\langle \delta,H\rangle $ does not exist, the distribution $\langle\delta,foH\rangle $ does not exist either.